# Logical operator OR problem: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Or operator does not work. could you help how to get it right.

```
$('.iconWrapper span').click(function(e) {
   $('#div1').find('img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
 if( src =='../../photo/roz1.jpg' || '../../photo/roz2.jpg'){
        alert ('ohra');
        }else{
        alert ('lil');
 }

});
```

Comment: Added the "JavaScript" tag an reformatted the code.

Comment: @Felix What I meant was jQuery is not a language, it's a library. A lot of people seem to think they're coding in jQuery, while not knowing about javascript. Case in point: this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( src =='../../photo/roz1.jpg' || src == '../../photo/roz2.jpg'){...
```

Comment: thanks i got it now, i had forgotten to have src in both side. it works

Comment: Many people say to themselves "if src equals option one or option two" - computers need it more explicitly than that ie "if src equals option one or src equals option two". Somewhat confusingly I think a string eg `'../../photo/roz2.jpg'` will actually evaluate to `true` in JavaScript. I recommend you read some of Crockford's stuff (see Tim's answer) regarding 'falsey' and 'truthy' values in JavaScript - as well as all the other wisdom the man imparts... :)

Answer (score 5):

It "does not work" because this operator does not exist in JavaScript (why do you think it does?)

It is `||`, and you have to test the condition explicitly: `var == val1 || var == val2`.

`var == (val1 || val2)` is doing something different.

```
if(src =='../../photo/roz1.jpg' || src == '../../photo/roz2.jpg')
```

See [**MDC - Logial Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript || is used for or. Your if should read something like this:

```
if( src == '../../photo/roz1.jpg' || src == '../../photo/roz2.jpg'){
```

You really need to leran the basiscs, checkout these as a starting point:

- [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
- [Douglas Crockford on JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/)
- [JavaScript the definitive guide](http://www.google.de/search?q=javascript%20the%20definitive%20guide)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add "src==" after or as well, and use || for or.

Comment: The main issue is that there is no `or` operator in JS.

Comment: @Tim probably because it doesn't fix the OP's issue and does not mention the fact that `or` is not a logical operator in JS

Comment: I fixed it, it's easy to overlook one problem when you find another one. Just changing to || would have left him with an if that always return true and probably even more confusion.. :-)